# How to plot with ggplot multiple bars in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im having trouble trying to plot the following dataset

```
Holiday_sales1 <- read.csv(text="
Holidays,Date,Weekly_Sales
Super bowl,2010-02-12,48336678
Labor Day,2010-09-10,45634398
Thanksgiving,2010-11-26,65821003
Christmas,2010-12-31,40432519
Super Bowl,2011-02-11,47336193
Labor Day,2011-09-09,46763228
Thanksgiving,2011-11-25,66593605
Christmas,2011-12-30,46042461
Super Bowl,2012-02-10,50009408
Labor Day,2012-09-07,48330059
", header=T)
Holiday_sales1$Date <- as.Date(Holiday_sales1$Date)
```

Im using this code

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Holiday_sales1, aes(x =Date, y=Weekly_Sales)) + geom_col(aes(fill=Holidays))
```

But the bars don't show as expected. For example 2010 only shows one bar even though the dataset contains 4 data points for that year.
[image]

will appreciate your feedback

Comment: Your `x` axis is continuous. Your bars appear where along the year the holiday itself appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is being displayed correctly. The issue is that since last 2 events in 2010 are at the end of the year the bars are being displayed closer to 2011 than 2010.

Maybe you could extract the year from the data and plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  mutate(year = lubridate::year(Date)) %>%
  ggplot() +  aes(x =  year, y=Sales, fill = Holidays) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge')
```

[image]